# Python 3 : How to append integer values for a key in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.4

I am a Newbie in Python programming : I am trying the following. Please guide:

I have a dictionary as following:

> dict1 = {'w' : 4,'e' : 5,'r' : 8}.

I Want to append the values in the dict1 as follows :

> dict = {'w' : (4,6),'e' : 5,'r' : 8}.

I have tried using update but it  replaces the key and inserts a new key.
*Is there any option to append the values for the key which we want*.
Is it possible to achieve?

If so, please let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this `dict1 ['key'] = 'value'`